# Why does the first image in this table only link part of the image to its hyperlink, but the second one works fine?

Tags: html

I'm unsure why the link for the first image in the table is messed up since it has the same structure as the second image which does work fine, it's just in a different location. I've copied the relevant sections of html below as block code

I'm new to html but have been able to make everything else work fine. Any help would be appreciated!

```css
#webpage {

width: 1000px ;

margin-left: auto ;

margin-right: auto ;

}



/* Pennant pos */

.pennant {

padding: 0px 0px;

position: absolute;

}



/* Logo pos */

.logo {

padding: 300px 0px;

position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<body style="color:white">

  <div id="webpage">

  <hr id="home">

  <br>

<table width="100%" border="0">

  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td valign="Top" align="Left">

        <div class="pennant">

          <a href="https://link1.com/">

             <img src="pennant.png" width="350" height="226">
          </a>

        </div>

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="Bottom" align="Left">

        <div class="logo">

          <a href="https://link2.com/">

            <img src="logo.png" width="257" height="95">

          </a>

        </div>

      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: start using a tutorial written at least in the last 30 years... tables are only for displaying data not for layout...

Comment: how do I arrange these items properly then? just telling my i'm wrong doesn't exactly help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but position of .pennant cannot be absolute, it moves the div into the other place than your image is, try removing it.

```
.pennant {

  padding: 0px 0px;

}
```

Comment: Np, have a nice coding! :)